# Passing Jenkins parameters to remote server

Tags: bash, jenkins

I am trying to run Jenkins job, To put the Jenkins parameters on different server, so i can run commands on the remote server , with parameters set in the Jenkins, executing shell .
I am trying to transferring the parameters via here-doc

Trying this code:

```
echo $BUILD_USER_ID $BUILD_DISPLAY_NAME

echo $servers > /tmp/servers.txt

for servers in `cat /tmp/servers.txt`; do

ssh -T $servers <<'EOF'

    
echo ${BUILD_NUMBER} ${BUILD_USER_ID} >/tmp/test

    
EOF

done < /tmp/log.txt > ${LOG}
```

Comment: What's your issue?

Comment: i need that the remote server will inherit the main Jenkins server 
it is retuning blank values 
just like passing values with here-doc, from server to server ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use [SSH Pipeline Steps](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/ssh-steps/) for this.

```
    def remote = [:]
    remote.name = 'test'
    remote.host = 'test.domain.com'
    remote.user = 'root'
    remote.password = 'password'
    remote.allowAnyHosts = true
    stage('Remote SSH') {
      sshCommand remote: remote, command: "ls -lrt"
      sshCommand remote: remote, command: "for i in {1..5}; do echo -n \"Loop \$i \"; date ; sleep 1; done"
    }
```